# Maxscript outputfile name with integer variable error

Tags: 3dsmax, maxscript

I'm saving the outputfile name of my renders with an integer variable that has his value added by 1 inside the loop. The problem is that I need the file name to be saved as the following nomenclature: "*ImageName-00.jpeg*",  "*ImageName-01.jpeg*"... so I can upload it to Turbosquid, but the file is being saved as "*ImageName-90001.jpeg*", "*ImageName-90002.jpeg*".

- Note by Turbosquid:

[image]

- Example as how the files are being saved:
  [image]

- Line of the code where I make the save:

  ```
   _frame = 0
   for current in assetsList do(
       render camera:c fromframe:0 toframe:10 outputfile:(turnPath + "\\" + currentName + "-" + _frame as string + ".jpeg")
       _frame += 1
   )
  ```

Answer (score 0):

One problem is that when you provide a frame range to render, 3ds Max is no longer in single-frame mode and it will append timestamps to your filenames. What happens in your case is the value `9` comes from `_frame`, and then 3ds Max is appending a 4-digit timestamp for the actual frame number being rendered: `0000`, `0001` *etc*.

Although it's less efficient, an easy way to get around this is to call `render` once for each frame. That puts the renderer in single-frame mode, and it won't add its own timestamps.

Now, you just need to build the output file name correctly. You can use the [formattedPrint](https://help.autodesk.com/view/MAXDEV/2023/ENU/?guid=GUID-19874C74-DEE5-4BCD-A5FD-4F0F51EB3451) function to zero-pad a number.

Putting this together:

```
for f = 0 to 10 do (
    local fileName = turnPath + @"\" + currentName + "-" + (formattedPrint f format:"02d") + ".jpeg"
    format "Rendering: %\n" fileName
    render camera:c frame:f outputfile:fileName
)
```